# How to fire a function on @State variable change from Apple Watch Digital Crown with SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, binding, state, watchkit, swiftui

The code below creates a ring in SwiftUI that is completed when the Digital Crown is rotated. I'd like to fire a function when the "crownValue" state variable reaches a value of 5.0, which is when the circle is fully visible.

How can I have a function that reacts to the crown value change in order to perform a web request?

Thanks

```
struct commandDetailView: View {

    @State var crownValue = 0.1


    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(crownValue / 5.0))
                .stroke(Color.blue, style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 12, lineCap: CGLineCap.round, lineJoin: .round))
                .frame(width: 120, height: 120)

            Text("Spin to Start Car")


        }
    .focusable(true)
        .digitalCrownRotation($crownValue, from: 0.1, through: 5.0, sensitivity: .low, isContinuous: false, isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true)
        .onAppear() {

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the easiest thing to do right now is use a custom binding that wraps your `crownValue`.  (I say unfortunately, as I have an open ticket with Apple about the lack of `didSet` for `@State` and how to work around it, with no resolution yet.)

```swift
var crownValueBinding: Binding<Double> {
  Binding<Double>(
    get: { self.crownValue },
    set: { newValue in
      self.crownValue = newValue
      self.myFunc() // Whatever you like
    }
  )
}
```

And to use it:

```
 SomeView()
   .digitalCrownRotation(self.crownValueBinding, ...) // NOTE: No $ sign!
```

Comment: Coming back to this with the same issue in another project, would you mind explaining why you omit the $ sign in the solution? I understand it's necessary but don't quite understand why.

Comment: `@State var crownValue ...` is a wrapped `@State` property. When you use `self.$crownValue` it accesses a `@State`'s "projected value" which is a `Binding`. However, `crownValueBinding` is *already* a `Binding` that we've explicitly created in that code. Check out [the documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html) for more. Search for "property wrapper" and "projected value" on that page.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, if you `import Combine`, you can do the following:

```
[...]
.focusable(true)
.digitalCrownRotation($crownValue, from: 0.1, through: 5.0, sensitivity: .low, isContinuous: false, isHapticFeedbackEnabled: true)
.onReceive(Just(crownValue)) { output in
    print(output) // Here is the answer.
}
```

Comment: No need for Combine if you use .onChange(of:perform:) instead of .onReceive(_:perform). You can even capture the old value in the closure if you need it.